# Bulk Update set of rowkeys with same value in hbase

Tags: hbase, bulkupdate

I have a set of rowkeys stored in an arrayList, and I want to bulk update the value of all the rowkeys in hbase with same value. Is it possible to do ?

Comment: so you want all the rows to have the same value for a particular column?

Comment: I want to update the value of rowkey to "done" as soon as the task using that rowkey is executed . I want to do bulk update(like in a group of 10 or something) to increase the speed of the application.

Comment: you will have to tell me how are you accessing hbase, so I can formulate an answer, there is something called BatchMutation which is fast.